# how can I dynamically create html components in Jsf2

Tags: jsf, richfaces, jsf-2

how can I dynamically create html components in Jsf2. I have to make a dynamic form which is to be filled by user, so I am not getting how can I manage, I have to use JavaScript or what??
I am using richfaces too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create dynamic JSF 1.2 form fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510614/how-to-create-dynamic-jsf-1-2-form-fields)

Comment: Hi BalusC actually i had a h:inputtext in which i feed a no.(Ex:8) and click generate button and I had to generate 8 columns in h:datatable ...so please give solution

Answer (score 0):

yes. use javascript. one way using js could be to have the various 'dynamic' html elements already on the page, but set to hidden via CSS: `display:none;`

when an element triggers a hidden element to be show, use js: `document.getElementById('xyz').style.display = 'block';`

Answer (score 0):

Here, you can use panelGrid component, specify no of columns dynamically.
You can then add other stuff into the panelGrid.

Page Code:

```
<ice:inputText value="#{bean.noOfColumns}"

<ice:panelGrid columns="#{bean.noOfColumns}" binding="#{bean.gridComponent}">
```

Backing Bean Code :

```
//---

for(int i=0; i < noOfColumns; i++)
     gridComponent.getChildren().add(uiComponent);

//---
```

You can add any uiComponent accordingly.

Comment: Then you can use <h:panelGrid> as it is core JSF component, if it fits well according to your need.