# XSLT to ICEFaces markup

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, icefaces

Is it possible to apply an XSLT to an XML document and generate markup that is processed by JSF/ICEFaces?

I need the XSLT to add `<ice:commandButton` elements and such, since some data elements to render also require related command buttons.

Do you also have some tutorials about XSLT and ICEFaces?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is definitely possible. You just need to create a servlet `Filter` which runs before the `FacesServlet` kicks in and takes care that the XSL-generated Facelet file is present there where the `FacesServlet` expects it. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510614/how-to-create-dynamic-jsf-1-2-form-fields/3511785#3511785) for a detailed kickoff example.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact syntax of ICEFaces but if you want output that is not following XML or HTML syntax rules then [disable-output-escaping](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#disable-output-escaping) (in XSLT 1.0 and 2.0) and [character maps](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#character-maps) (in XSLT 2.0) can help. The character maps documentation I linked to has an example to create JSF syntax.

Comment: What I need is that ICEfaces uses the XSLT output to **render server-side controls**. So an ice:commandButton tag as result of transformation should be processed by server (not sent to client directly) to generate an input tag that will be rendered by the client