# Dynamic Action in JSF page

Tags: jsf, icefaces

I have a JSF page. My CommandButton action method value is dependent on the bean variable value.
Example:
Bean headerBean has varaible actionValue with value "someBean.doAction1()"

When I use  , It says headerBean.actionValue is not a method which is right.

How can I get the action value as "someBean.doAction1" instead of headerBean.actionValue.

Thanks,

Comment: can you post a little sample of what you have now?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the brace notation for that.

```
<h:commandButton value="submit" action="#{someBean[headerBean.actionValue]}" />
```

When the `#{headerBean.actionValue}` returns a String of for example `doAction1`, then this will effectively invoke `#{someBean.doAction1}`.

If the bean name to be called is currently actually in the `actionvalue` (`headerBean.actionValue` returning `someBean.doAction1`), you need to split it into a field that returns the bean name and one that returns the method name and then use

```
<h:commandButton value="submit" action="#{requestScope[headerBean.beanName][headerBean.actionValue]}" />
```

If `headerBean.beanName` returns 'someBean' and `headerBean.actionValue` returns `doAction1` the above will call `#{somebean.doAction1}`.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for replying. My headerBean.actionValue returns someBean.doAction1. I think using your solution makes it [code]#{someBean.someBean.doAction1}[code]. The value of headerBean.actionValue also return the bean name.

Comment: that's interesting -- i didn't realize that syntax works. thanks for the info.

Comment: wow. interesting syntax. I usually do something this similar with reflection, like generate the method name at runtime and use reflection to invoke it. Nice to know that I can do it in JSF as well. +1

Comment: @mahesh: you should split that on the period and then use something like (assuming that bean is request scoped) `#{requestScope[headerBean.beanName][headerBean.beanAction]}`. @Harry: I think you may find this example useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713718/how-to-make-a-grid-of-jsf-composite-component/5716633#5716633