# Display dialog window if some criteria is not met in JSF form

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I'm trying to implement JSF button with AJAX which form with AJAX if some criteria is not met. I tried this example:

```
<h:form id="paymentform" enctype="multipart/form-data" x:data-form-output="form-output-global" x:data-form-type="contact" class="rd-mailform text-left">

<h:commandButton id="buy" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Put" action="#{dashboard.calculateProcessing}"  >
    <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form" x:data-toggle="modal" x:data-target="#demoModal"/>  // if #{dashboard.amount} <= 0 call modal dialog 
</h:commandButton>

<div class="modal fade" id="demoModal" role="dialog">
.....
</div>

</h:form>



@Named
@SessionScoped
public class Dashboard implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2363083605115312742L;

    private double amount;

    public double getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(double amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }
}
```

If I edit the button this way:

```
<h:commandButton id="buy" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Put" action="#{dashboard.calculateProcessing}" x:data-toggle="modal" x:data-target="#demoModal" >
```

The dialog is display and the form is submitted.

But I can't find a solution how to not submit the form if some criteria from the Bean is not met. Can you guide me how to find a solution?

<Removed blatant begging for help, see edits>

Comment: I updated the answer. This is what I can think of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to execute an `f:ajax` based on a criteria in your bean. Basically the `f:ajax` should get rendered when the criteria is true and else then not.
Every JSF component has a `rendered` value.

Your code should look like this:

```
<h:commandButton id="buy" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Put" action="#{dashboard.calculateProcessing}"  >
    <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form" x:data-toggle="modal" x:data-target="#demoModal" rendered="#{dashboard.amount <= 0}"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

This also can be done with more than one `f:ajax` like this:

```
<h:commandButton>
    <f:ajax render="@form" rendered="#{bean.condition}" />
    <f:ajax execute="@form" rendered="#{bean.int < 0}" />
    <f:ajax action="#{bean.action}" rendered="#{bean.property == null}" />
</h:commandButton>
```

Basically if a `rendered` attribute is false it will not result in the HTML the client receives. [More about rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870462/conditionally-displaying-jsf-components)

You can also use [jstl tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense) to define if a component gets rendered.
Use like this:

```
<h:commandButton>
    <c:if test="#{bean.condition}>
        <!-- f:ajax here-->
    </c:if>

    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="#{bean.condition}">
            <!-- f:ajax here-->
        </c:when>

        <c:otherwise>
            <!-- f:ajax here-->
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
</h:commandButton>
```

For calling dynamic actions in for example a `commandButton` see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219907/dynamic-action-in-jsf-page).