# How to pass some ID of h:inputText to a bean in action

Tags: java, jsf-2

I'm using JSF 2.0 with GF3.1

I have many h:inputTexts on my page and want to format their size on some conditions depending their ID.

My bean method:

```
  public String doSize(Object obj) {
    if (obj.equals(...)) 
        return "5";
    else
        return "10";
  }
```

And my JSF page:

```
....
<h:inputText id="some1" value="#{myBean.values['1']}" 
   size="{myBean.doSize(this)}" />
.... (another inputTexts) ....
```

I always get null passed to bean. Is there any way to pass something that idetifies my inputText? Or any way to set size in some other stage? Where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `#{component}`. It refers to the current [`UIComponent`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html) which is in this particular case of subtype [`UIInput`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html).

```html
<h:inputText id="some1" value="#{myBean.values['1']}" 
    size="#{myBean.doSize(component)}" />
```

You can even explicitly pass the ID which is obtained from [`UIComponent#getId()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getId%28%29):

```html
<h:inputText id="some1" value="#{myBean.values['1']}" 
    size="#{myBean.doSize(component.id)}" />
```

Comment: Thanks @BalusC, that's what I needed. An extra question: passing component.id to bean works great, I get my id. While doing value binding same way: value="#{myBean.values[component.id])" binds not to my id but to some j_idt6 name....

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work that way in values. The default `id` is been obtained before the fixed `id` is been set. You might want to parameterize the string "some1" instead, e.g. by `<ui:param>` so that you don't need to repeat it. Or, have a look at tag files like as the example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713718/how-to-make-a-grid-of-jsf-composite-component/5716633#5716633