# Reusing a form in two different views JSF

Tags: jsf, facelets

Is it possible to reuse a form in two different views in JSF? I know about the `ui:include` but how would you do it with the action on the submit button for example? Or do I need to duplicate the forms?

Comment: Sure, I use the same form in a bunch of different views.  But I dont really understand your question.  Can you expand on your concern about the action of the submit button?  The submit button is part of the form itself, so how would that be effected by the view it is contained in (other than possibly a different id due to naming container)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using `<ui:include>` you can parameterize the bean and/or the method by `<ui:param>`.

```html
<ui:include src="...">
  <ui:param name="bean" value="#{someBeanName}" />
  <ui:param name="action" value="someMethodName" />
</ui:include>
```

with

```html
<h:commandButton ... action="#{someBeanName[someMethodName]}" />
```

You can also make it a Facelets tag file instead so that you end up with something like

```html
<my:someForm bean="#{someBeanName}" action="someMethodName" />
```

A composite component is also doable, but IMO not *really* the right approach for this purpose.

#### See also:

- [When to use <ui:include>, tag files, composite components and/or custom components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822000/when-to-use-uiinclude-tag-files-composite-components-and-or-custom-componen)
- [Our Composite Component wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/composite-component/info)

Comment: I am reading on how to make composite components now. What would you do? Used the ui:include with parameters as you described?

Comment: Depends really on the functional purpose of that form and what you would like to do on those 2 cases. For example, is it one for data input and other for data editing? If so, `ui:include` would make more sense. Or is it kind of a confirmation form which you *can* basically reuse on *every* other page/form? If so, a tag file would make more sense. If it had to represent for example a single input field, a composite component would make more sense, which clearly isn't the case if it's already a whole form.

Comment: This form will be used for both editing and adding questions on the admin side and also for adding new questions on the public/client side.

Comment: And may I ask what the tag file is (I did try to search, did not find any correct sources for further reading)? I have not heard or read anything about that yet, I think.

Comment: I'd just start off with an include. As to tag files, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713718/how-to-make-a-grid-of-jsf-composite-component/5716633#5716633

Comment: Thank you, your help is much appriciated:) I forgot one thing though, if the form will have different backing beans (since the form will be used for both admin and the public side) then how would I do it? Should I make a base class that both beans inherit from so the property I use in the form is available in the form?

Comment: A base class is only useful if the beans share common properties which is I think indeed true in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use composite components. Those components can be parameterized so that you could exchange the backing bean, etc..

IBM has some nice guides on that topic.

[Composite components part 1 + 2 and best practices.](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/views/java/libraryview.jsp?search_by=JSF+fu%3a)

Comment: Exactly, I will look at it =)