# JSF 1.2 : Can I create reusable component inside JSF view

Tags: jsf, components, code-reuse

Is possible to something like this in jsf?

```
<ui:composition>
  <x:reusableCode id="editScreen">InnerHtml ... </x:reusableCode>
  code...
  <x:use component="editScreen"/>
</ui:composition
```

I know I can create my own component and register it in jsf tagLib, but I need reusable HTML only in on jsf view file.

Comment: Sorry, i forget add this to summary. I use 1.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Facelets 1.x you can create a tag file for this purpose.

Here's a basic kickoff example. Create `/WEB-INF/tags/some.xhtml`:

```
<ui:composition 
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
>
    <h:outputText value="#{foo}" />
</ui:composition>
```

Define it in `/WEB-INF/my.taglib.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE facelet-taglib PUBLIC
    "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Facelet Taglib 1.0//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/dtd/facelet-taglib_1_0.dtd">

<facelet-taglib>
    <namespace>http://example.com/jsf/facelets</namespace>
    <tag>
        <tag-name>some</tag-name>
        <source>/WEB-INF/tags/some.xhtml</source>
    </tag>
</facelet-taglib>
```

Register it in `/WEB-INF/web.xml`:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.LIBRARIES</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/my.taglib.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

*(note, when you have multiple, use semicolon `;` to separate them)*

Finally just declare it in your main page templates.

```
<ui:composition 
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:my="http://example.com/jsf/facelets"
>
    <my:some foo="value1" />
    <my:some foo="value2" />
    <my:some foo="value3" />
</ui:composition>
```

A more advanced example can be found here: [How to make a grid of JSF composite component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713718/how-to-make-a-grid-of-jsf-composite-component/5716633#5716633) Note: JSF 2.0 targeted, but with minor changes based on above example it works as good on Facelets 1.x.

Comment: Thanks for this approach, but i thought there is method to create reusable component inside one jsf file, without any tag registration.  :)

Comment: This works, except for the `<source>/WEB-INF/tags/some.xhtml</source>` element in the `my.taglib.xml`. I had to change it to `<source>tags/some.xhtml</source>` to make it work.