# Primefaces outputLabel for composite component

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, composite-component

I have an issue with using `p:outputLabel` when used with composite component. I have composite component with `p:inputText` field (I removed irrelevant parts from component):

```
<cc:interface>
  <cc:editableValueHolder name="myInput" targets="myInput"/>
  <cc:attribute name="required" required="true" type="java.lang.Boolean" default="false"/>
</cc:interface>

<cc:implementation>
  <p:inputText id="myInput" required="#{cc.attrs.required}"/>
</cc:implementation>
```

Now, I wont to use this component with `p:outputLabel`:

```
<p:outputLabel for="myComponent:myInput" value="#{resources['myLabel']}:"/>
<my:myComponent id="myComponent" required="#{myBean.required}"/>
```

Everything works fine, required validation, message is displayed as well, but there is no `*` sign on label, as there is when I connect label directly to `p:inputText` component. If I, on the other hand, hardcode `required="true"` on `p:inputText` everything works fine.

I debugged through `org.primefaces.component.outputlabel.OutputLabelRenderer` and discovered that component is recognized as `UIInput`, but `input.isRequired()` returns false. Farther debugging discovered that `required` attribute isn't yet defined on component, so it returns `false` as default value i `UIInput`:

```
(Boolean) getStateHelper().eval(PropertyKeys.required, false);
```

Also, if I just move `p:outputLabel` inside composite component everything works fine. Like EL is evaluated later inside composite component?

I'm using Primefaces 3.5 with Mojarra 2.1.14

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is, unfortunately, "by design". The evaluation of the `#{}` expressions is deferred to the exact moment of the access-time. They're unlike "standard" EL `${}` in JSP *not* evaluated at the exact moment they're been parsed by the tag handler and "cached" for future access during the same request/view. At the moment the `<p:outputLabel>` is rendered, and thus the `#{cc.attrs.required}` as referenced by `UIInput#isRequired()` needs to be evaluated, there's no means of any `#{cc}` in the EL context. So any of its attributes would not evaluate to anything. Only when you're sitting inside the `<cc:implementation>`, the `#{cc}` is available in the EL context and all of its attribues would thus successfully evaluate.

Technically, this is an unfortunate corner case oversight in the design of `<p:outputLabel>`. Standard JSF and EL are namely behaving as specified. Basically, the presentation of the label's asterisk depending on the input's `required` attribute should be evaluated the other way round: at the moment the `<p:inputText>` inside the composite is to be rendered or perhaps even already when it's to be built. Thus, the label component should not ask the input component if it's required, but the input component should somehow notify the label component that it's required. This is in turn hard and clumsy (and thus inefficient) to implement.

If moving the label to inside the composite is not an option, then your best bet is to create a tag file instead of a composite component around the input component. It only requires some additional XML boilerplate.

`/WEB-INF/tags/input.xhtml`:

```
<ui:composition
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
>
    <c:set var="id" value="#{not empty id ? id : 'myInput'}" />
    <c:set var="required" value="#{not empty required and required}" />

    <p:inputText id="#{id}" required="#{required}"/>
</ui:composition>
```

`/WEB-INF/my.taglib.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<facelet-taglib
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facelettaglibrary_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0"
>
    <namespace>http://example.com/my</namespace>

    <tag>
        <tag-name>input</tag-name>
        <source>tags/input.xhtml</source>
    </tag>
</facelet-taglib>
```

`/WEB-INF/web.xml`:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/my.taglib.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Usage:

```
<html ... xmlns:my="http://example.com/my">
...
<p:outputLabel for="myInput" value="#{resources['myLabel']}:" />
<my:input id="myInput" required="#{myBean.required}" />
```

I just did a quick test and it works fine for me.

#### See also:

- [When to use <ui:include>, tag files, composite components and/or custom components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822000/when-to-use-uiinclude-tag-files-composite-components-and-or-custom-componen/6822269#6822269)

Comment: This works for me. Only reason why I can't put label inside composite component is because this input will be used in some `panelGrid`, one column for label and one for input. With this it will be hard make this looks acceptable.

Comment: Then using a tag file instead of a composite component has an extra advantage for you: a tag file is unlike a composite component not interpreted as a single component! You can in fact safely put the label next the input in the tag file and still end up with 2 cells. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713718/how-to-make-a-grid-of-jsf-composite-component This should further reduce the boilerplate.

Comment: I've found a way using `o:tagAttribute` but it's available starting 2.1 while we're using 1.14, do you have plan to create a new release in the future that might include this?

Comment: @Rapster Nope, 1.1x is end of life. JSF 2.3 was introduced a few months ago and it has a required CDI dependency. So all focus will be on OmniFaces 2.x and 3.x.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer @BalusC

Comment: To add a relevant comment to this post, `p:outputLabel` supports composite now, see migration guide https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/wiki/Migration-Guide#60-to-61 but more i think about it, more I think the use case is wrong (using composite) while facelet should be used instead. More explanations explained here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MYFACES-4059