# Component inside Composite referencing another component inside other component

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, composite-component

I created a [Composite Component](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giqzr.html) to emulate the [Primefaces's Column](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/4.0/primefaces-p/columns.html), which instead render to  components, its renderize to  (I also created other components to emulate Primefaces's [PanelGrid](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/4.0/primefaces-p/panelGrid.html) and [Row](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/4.0/primefaces-p/row.html) to use DIVs instead Table and TR). The code is the following:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" 
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" 
    xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="id" type="java.lang.String" required="false"/>
    <cc:attribute name="span" type="java.lang.Integer" required="false" default="1" />
</cc:interface>
<cc:implementation>
    <p:outputPanel id="#{cc.attrs.id}" layout="block"
        styleClass="ui-grid-col-#{cc.attrs.span}">
        <cc:insertChildren />
    </p:outputPanel>
</cc:implementation>
</html>
```

My problem happens when I use a outputLabel referrecing a component to an outside's component:

```
<ipem:column span="2">
    <p:outputLabel value="#{msg['precadastro.titulo.nome_fantasia']}" for="fantasia"/>
</ipem:column>
<ipem:column span="10">
    <p:inputText id="fantasia" size="80" maxlength="100"
        value="#{preCadastroMB.preCadastro.nomeFantasia}" />
</ipem:column>
```

When I wrote this, I got the message `Cannot find component with identifier "fantasia" referenced from "painelCadastro:j_idt80:j_idt82:j_idt84".` I need remove the `for` attribute in outputLabel.

I found some questions here in StackOverflow which are near my doubt. For example, in [How to make a grid of JSF composite component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713718/how-to-make-a-grid-of-jsf-composite-component) we have an outputLabel in the parent page which references a component inside a composite. However, in my case, both label as inputText are inside its own composite. In [How to create a composite component for a datatable column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11439886/how-to-create-a-composite-component-for-a-datatable-column) the label and inputText are both in the same composite.

We don't have this problem Column's Primefaces. How do they manage this?

Thanks,

Rafael Afonso

Comment: The code in this answer does what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15002441/primefaces-outputlabel-for-composite-component

Comment: @Yamada: Thanks, but this answer falls in the same problem as _How to make a grid of JSF composite component?_: An outputLabel in the parent page which references a component inside a composite, when I want both label as inputText are inside their own composites.

Comment: Can you confirm that you have tested using for="myTargetCompositeComponent:fantasia" in the p:outputLabel and set id="myTargetCompositeComponent" in the target cc (<ipem:column span="10" id="myTargetCompositeComponent">)?

Comment: @Yamada: What I really want is discover how to make a reference to a component outside a composite in the same way as we would do in a panelGrid. For example, `<p:panelGrid> ... <p:row><p:column> <p:outputLabel for="fantasia"/></p:column> <p:column><p:inputText id="fantasia" /> </p:column></p:row> ... <p:panelGrid>`. I don't want to appeal to references using ":".

Comment: Well, if you don't want to define and use the full component identifier, another alternative would be using JQuery selectors. Primefaces has some support for it. Have a look in http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=1867

Comment: I'm relatively new to JSF but it appears that this is what `composite:editableValueHolder` is for. Have you tried using that? It will let you pass in a reference to another component. See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giqzr.html or https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jsf2fu0111/ for more info.