# Can I make JSF2 skip rendering my custom tag without modifying the tag itself?

Tags: jsf-2, custom-tags

I've started my own custom taghandler (pure XHTML, no Renderer) using [BalusC's template](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5716633/785663), let's call it `bean:input` - the typical label, input, message trio. It's used like this:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="3">
   <bean:input label="input1:" bean="#{bean1}" property="name" />
   <bean:input label="input2:" bean="#{bean2}" property="name" />
   <bean:input label="input3:" bean="#{bean3}" property="name" />
</h:panelGrid>
```

Trouble is, the inputs are mutually exclusive (ie, only one of them should appear). Which input is shown is determined at render time by a view parameter. How do I do this?

I can't use `<ui:fragment>` as this would mess up the `panelGrid`, specifying `rendered="false"` on the tag had no effect and I kind of hesitate to wrap my tag implementation in a big `<c:if test="#{rendered}">` - is there a better/builtin way to tell JSF it should simply skip rendering this specific tag?

---

Note: the `<c:if>` tag does funny things (like rendering a label that shouldn't be rendered, but not the corresponding input box) when I re-render the grid with a partial update. Adding the `rendered` attribute to the components themselves fixes that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add support for `rendered` attribute to the tag file and re-apply it on tag file's contents.

```
<bean:input label="input1:" bean="#{bean1}" property="name" rendered="..." />
```

---

> *I kind of hesitate to wrap my tag implementation in a big `<c:if test="#{rendered}">`*

It's maybe ugly, but yes that's a way.

Comment: "Adding support" here means applying it to all child components or plain `<c:if>` in the custom tagfile?

Comment: Your choice. The `<c:if>` runs during view build time. The `<h:xxx rendered>` runs during view render time. If you have view scoped beans and are using Mojarra older than 2.1.18, then `<c:if>` breaks view scoped beans if the property behind `rendered` attribute references a view scoped bean property.

Comment: Since I can control the environment, I have upgraded to Mojarra-2.1.22 and am now using `<c:if>` in the tagfile. Thanks for the answer!