# Two ui:include in one page and ui:param not working properly

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, facelets

I'm using primefaces 3.5 with JSF mojarra 2.2.
I've a page with two ui:include which are wrapped in a p:dialog and ui:param is being used to pass values in/out of the includes.

```
<p:dialog header="Customer Selection Criteria" widgetVar="customerSelectionDialog" width="1200" position="center" appendToBody="true">
    <h:form id="customerForm">
        <p:outputPanel id="customerSelection">
            <ui:include src="../INTERNAL/8500.xhtml">
                <ui:param name="showCidSelect" value="1" /> 
                <ui:param name="targetObject" value="#{customerDetailsInquiry.cf8444.cg1014.cg1014cidnumb}" />
            </ui:include>
            <p:commandButton rendered="false" value="#{COMMON.COMMON_SELECTBUTTON}" action="#{customerDetailsInquiry.tchelp.handleReturnFromCustomerSelectionCriteria}" oncomplete="customerSelectionDialog.hide();" update=":mainForm:cf8444icg1014c1002" >
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{customerSearchEngine}" target="#{flash.customerSearchEngine}"/>
            </p:commandButton>
        </p:outputPanel>
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
<p:dialog closeOnEscape="true" modal="true" appendToBody="false" header="Entity Stack" widgetVar="entityStackDialog" width="400" >
    <h:form id="entityForm">
        <ui:include src="../INTERNAL/StackedEntity.xhtml">
            <ui:param name="displayCaption" value="CID Numbers" />
            <ui:param name="department" value="8" /> 
            <ui:param name="stackedObject" value="#{customerDetailsInquiry.cf8444.cg1014.cg1014cidnumb}" />
        </ui:include>
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

Backing Bean:

```
FaceletContext faceletContext = (FaceletContext) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getAttributes().get(FaceletContext.FACELET_CONTEXT_KEY);
String paramValue = (String) faceletContext.getAttribute("showCidSelect");
```

now the problem is with "**showCidSelect**" parameter.

**showCidSelect** determines whether to show "**select**" button in **8500.xhtml** or not.

Since "**showCidSelect**" in this above example is set to "1", select button should be rendered.

Without the second dialog for "**StackedEntity.xhtml**" this works perfectly fine.

But when i put second dialog and its ui:param's this stops working and FaceletContext getAttribute call returns null.

As of now i'm forced to include "**showCidSelect**" in both dialogs, then everything works fine. But i somehow feel there is some other better possible solution for this problem.

Request expert help

Comment: Getting the same issue - did you solve it?

Comment: No. But as of day, i'm simply replicating all the parameters(Even if they are not being used) in all ui:include's. Some Thing like this  <ui:include src="../INTERNAL/8500.xhtml">
                <ui:param name="showCidSelect" value="1" /> 
                <ui:param name="targetObject" value="#{customerDetailsInquiry.cf8444.cg1014.cg1014cidnumb}" /><ui:param name="displayCaption" value="CID Numbers" />
            <ui:param name="department" value="8" /> 
            <ui:param name="stackedObject" value="#{customerDetailsInquiry.cf8444.cg1014.cg1014cidnumb}" />
            </ui:include>

Answer (score 0):

It actually **solved** the same problem here by rewriting `ui:include` and `ui:param` to a custom JSF tag in a taglib.

Then you have a nice and easy to reuse tag, like:

```
<widgets:showCustomerSelector targetObject="#{customerDetailsInquiry.cf8444.cg1014.cg1014cidnumb}" />
```

And:

```
<widgets:stackedEntity displayCaption="CID Numbers" department="8" stackedObject="#{customerDetailsInquiry.cf8444.cg1014.cg1014cidnumb}" />
```

And then add new namespace to each JSF page/template where you use it (of, course):

`xmlns:widgets="http://your-company/jsf/widgets/customer"`

And write a taglib:

`WEB-INF/widgets.jsf.taglib.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<facelet-taglib version="2.2"
                xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facelettaglibrary_2_2.xsd">
    <namespace>http://your-company/jsf/widgets/customer</namespace>
    <tag>
        <tag-name>showCustomerSelector</tag-name>
        <description>@TODO Document this. Here goes your 8500.xhtml You had it in INTERNAL, better put templates in e.g. WEB-INF/templates/group/sub-group/ to have it out of document-root.</description>
        <source>resources/tags/show_customer_selector.xhtml</source>
        <attribute>
            <name>targetObject</name>
            <description>@TODO Document this.</description>
            <required>true</required>
            <!-- @TODO Find a **WAY** better type-hint, like an interface? -->
            <type>java.lang.Object</type>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <name>rendered</name>
            <description>Whether this tag is being rendered by JSF engine.    </description>
            <required>false</required>
            <type>java.lang.Boolean</type>
        </attribute>
    </tag>
    <tag>
        <tag-name>stackedEntity</tag-name>
        <description>@TODO Document this. Here goes your StackedEntity.xhtml - keep file names lower_under_scored to avoid case-sensitive problems!</description>
        <source>resources/tags/stacked_entity.xhtml</source>
        <attribute>
            <name>displayCaption</name>
            <description>@TODO Document this.</description>
            <required>true</required>
            <type>java.lang.String</type>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <name>department</name>
            <description>@TODO Document this.</description>
            <required>true</required>
            <type>java.lang.Number</type>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <name>rendered</name>
            <description>Whether this tag is being rendered by JSF engine.    </description>
            <required>false</required>
            <type>java.lang.Boolean</type>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <name>stackedObject</name>
            <description>@TODO Document this.</description>
            <required>true</required>
            <!-- @TODO Find a **WAY** better type-hint, like an interface? -->
            <type>java.lang.Object</type>
        </attribute>
    </tag>
</facelet-taglib>
```

And finally, register it in `web.xml`:

```
<context-param>
    <description>JSF widget tags library</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/widgets.jsf.taglib.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: **Important**: You have to include even common attributes (if you wish to use them) like `id`, `rendered`. Omitting the last one and then using it when you use your tag results your tag being **shown** as **any** not registered attribute will be ignored by JSF engine!

Source/credits: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473377/can-i-make-jsf2-skip-rendering-my-custom-tag-without-modifying-the-tag-itself?answertab=active#tab-top @BalusC

Comment: So your `resources/tags/stacked_entity.xhtml` (and all opthers) **must** do something like: `<h:panelGroup layout="block" rendered="#{rendered}">` and closing `</h:panelGroup>` at the end.