# <f:param> tags in composite component for surrounding <h:outputLink> and strange behaviour of <c:forEach>

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jstl, facelets, composite-component

I need to write a composite component that is placed inside an `<h:outputLink>...</h:outputLink>` tag and outputs `<f:param ... />` tags. The source for the generated `<f:param />` tags is a request attribute set by a filter, which contains a list of objects that provide the values for the attributes `name` and `value`.

There are now two problems:

1. The `<f:param />` tags do not affect the URL generated by the surrounding `<h:outputLink>`
2. `<c:forEach>` does not iterate over the list retrieved from the request attribute.

In General the whole component behaves a little bit strange, as I can access a specific element of the list and output its values. But, as soon as it comes to `<c:forEach>` the loop does not output anything.

The component currently looks as follows:

```
<f:view xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:cc="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite"
        xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core"
        xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">

  <!-- INTERFACE -->
  <cc:interface>
  </cc:interface>

  <!-- IMPLEMENTATION -->
  <cc:implementation>
    <!-- works, outputs e.g. 'confirmationData' -->
    #{activeContentThreadList[0].name}

    <!-- does not work, link URL is unaffected -->
    <f:param name="#{activeContentThreadList[0].displayName}"
             value="#{activeContentThreadList[0].token}" />

    <!-- works, outputs e.g. '[some.package.class@7951a73c]' -->
    <h:outputText value="#{activeContentThreadList}" />

    <!-- does not work, nothing is outputted -->
    <c:forEach items="#{activeContentThreadList}" var="asd">
      <h:outputText value="#{asd.name}" />
      <h:outputText value="test in loop" />
    </c:forEach>
  </cc:implementation>
</f:view>
```

The component is used as follows:

```
<h:outputLink value="#{request.contextPath}/confirmation/fields/ordersearch.xhtml" styleClass="ext">
  <cst:activeThreads />
</h:outputLink>
```

**my questions:**

- Why can I access a specific list item, but `<c:forEach>` doesn't do anything?
- Why is the link URL not affected by at least the single `<f:param>` tag?
- Is it even possible to output `<f:param>` tags from an inner composite component to the surrounding link?

Comment: Hey marius, hopefully you got the described problemhandled. If so, please confirm the answer below. :-)

Comment: Of course I will, just got back to office. I tried `<ui:repeat>` and it didn't change anything. So it is not possible to generate `<f:param>` tags that affect the surrounding link. I ended up using only one `<f:param>` with a static parameter name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For JSF, Composite Components are an own UIContainer. So the `h:outputLink`-tag does not see the `<f:param />` as a direct child of itself and that's why will ignore it. You can possibly work around that by implementing the tag not as Composite component but as a Facelet Custom Component (see ["how-to-make-a-grid-of-jsf-composite-component"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713718/how-to-make-a-grid-of-jsf-composite-component) as example). The taglib-xml does more or less only point to your [xhtml](/questions/tagged/xhtml) to be included, which is not that much more offset.

Regarding the `<c:forEach />`: The JSTL-Core attributes are breaking JSFcode on some positions, because they become rendered before JSF does. In this case, why not try to replace the `<c:forEach />` with a `<ui:repeat />` ?

Hope it helps...

Comment: I thought about a custom component but thought it might be too heavy-weight, but obviously it is not. Unfortunately something of your answer was cut off. With what should I replace `<c:foreach>`?

Comment: Hi marius. okay, corrected the typo. Well, the custom component is not that much more work. I sometimes even prefer it, because it imo handles given parameters (methods, beans,...) better and more error-prone then composite components. If I find a nice tutorial broken down to the point, I'll attach it to the answer, too... good luck with your work! L.