# TagException ... null (File not found) on creating custom Facelets tag

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, glassfish, facelets

I am creating an application based on JSF 2.2 (Mojarra). I am using a Java EE EAR project and a Dynamic Web project generated by Eclipse, and the Glassfish server.

I created a Facelet tag file as shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/5716633/2266635 . When I load a page containing the tag I get this error (and a HTTP 500 error):

```
2014-03-24T00:32:10.904+0100|WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
javax.faces.view.facelets.TagException: /index.xhtml @19,19 <fmk:login-form> null
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.UserTagHandler.apply(UserTagHandler.java:144)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:190)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:87)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:161)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:972)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:99)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
```

I have also tried to copy the example at http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/custom-tags-in-jsf-2-0/ verbatim, and I'm still getting the error (with a different tag).

The error at line 144 of UserTagHandler.java is a FileNotFoundException. If I supply an invalid file as `<source>` in the taglib definition file, I get the same error! So it never finds the file with the tag source code.

Here is a screenshot of the file tree: http://www.fa2k.net/misc/project.png (sorry, not allowed to post inline images yet)

Snippets from relevant files:

`WEB-INF/web.xml`

```
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/famake.taglib.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
```

`WEB-INF/famake.taglib.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<facelet-taglib version="2.2"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facelettaglibrary_2_2.xsd">
    <namespace>http://famake.com/jsf/facelets</namespace>
    <tag>
        <tag-name>login-form</tag-name>
        <source>tags/login-form.xhtml</source>
    </tag>
</facelet-taglib>
```

`WEB-INF/tags/login-form.xhtml`:

```
<ui:composition
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">

    Test tag

</ui:composition>
```

`index.xhtml`:

```
...
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:fmk="http://famake.com/jsf/facelets">
    <h:body>
        <h1>Custome Tags in JSF 2.0</h1>
        <fmk:login-form/>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

I don't understand why Glassfish can't find my `login-form.xhtml` . I have tried different paths and even tried strace'ing glassfish, but without any sensible results... Any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the server configuration. I couldn't find the cause, but it worked on a different Glassfish instance, so I just deleted the domain and re-created it. Sorry I couldn't find anything more specific.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same problem, my project (Glassfish 4 + Spring + EJB 3 + JSF 2.2 + Custom Tags) was running fine on my local Glassfish and on a staging server, but on Production it was throwing an exception `TagException: /WEB-INF/templates/common.xhtml @38,33 <app:div> null`.

After a lot of debugging we found out the problem. If your Glassfish have more than one virtual server configured and your project is deployed and associated with 2 or more, the JSF lib reads the sources files through the current host name you are accessing it, however for custom facelets tags **it reads through a different virtual server** (probably a bug) and throws a `FileNotFoundException` (suppressed by `TagException`).

If you configure your deployed project to only one virtual server, this problem does not occur. That's why when you re-created a fresh domain, it worked, because there was no extra virtual servers.

Comment: No need to repost the same answer over multiple questions. Just report the question as dupe (which I already did). This site is a Q&A site, not an old fashioned discussion forum.