# JSF Composite pass all events

Tags: jsf, events, inheritance, primefaces, composite-component

I want to create my custom composite component in JSF (with primefaces) that shows a label in front of an input an adds a message at the end.

In order to do that here is my source code:

The composite:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">
    <composite:interface componentType="customInput">
        <composite:attribute name="label" />
        <composite:attribute name="value" />
    </composite:interface>

    <composite:implementation>
        <h:panelGrid columns="3">
            <h:outputText value="#{cc.attrs.label}:" />
            <p:inputText id="abcde" value="#{cc.attrs.value}" />
            <p:message for="abcde" />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </composite:implementation>
</html>
```

The backing bean:

```
@FacesComponent(value = "customInput")
public class CustomInput extends InputText implements NamingContainer {
    @Override
    public String getFamily() {
        return UINamingContainer.COMPONENT_FAMILY;
    }
}
```

So far, so good. Now I want to use the events inherited by the p:inputText component. Like for example:

```
<pch2:PchInputText2 label="Name" id="test2" value="#{testBean.test}">
    <p:ajax event="blur" listener="#{chantierFormBean.updateMap()}" />
    <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{chantierFormBean.updateMap()}" />
</pch2:PchInputText2>
```

I know that I could pass these events by adding

```
<composite:clientBehavior name="change" event="change" targets="abcde" />
```

to the composite:interface part, but then I have to add one client behavior for every event (in the future). Isn't there a method to pass all events inherited by the primefaces inputtext?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not possible.

A composite is in first place not the right tool for this job. It's not primarily intented to DRY out and refactor repeated XHTML code. It's intented to create a whole new (input) component tied to a single model value. For example, a `<p:fileUpload>` and `<p:imageCropper>` togeher which is tied to a single `com.example.Image` property. Or three `<p:selectOneMenu>` together which is tied to a single `java.time.LocalDate` property.

Use a tagfile instead.

```
<ui:composition ...>
    <h:outputLabel for="#{id}" value="#{label}:" />
    <p:inputText id="#{id}" value="#{value}">
        <ui:insert />
    </p:inputText>
    <p:message for="#{id}" />
</ui:composition>
```

#### See also:

- [How to make a grid of JSF composite component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713718/how-to-make-a-grid-of-jsf-composite-component)
- [When to use <ui:include>, tag files, composite components and/or custom components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822000/when-to-use-uiinclude-tag-files-composite-components-and-or-custom-componen)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try to make it work with a tagfile. Does anyone knows if it possible to keep the funktionality of primefaces inputtext with this method? I will keep the attributes of p:inputtext without redefining them (like "rendered", "disbled", ...).

Comment: You don't need to explicitly define attributes in taglib.xml. Only the IDE autocomplete will suffer from this.

Comment: What I meant is when I use your sample composition code and want to use it like this:
<test:input value="#{backbean.input}" />
I can not add a "rendered=false" attribute without specifing it in the composition. Is there a way I can "pass" all attributes that <p:inputtext> already specifies?

Comment: No, just use `rendered="#{rendered ne false}"`. It's not different in composites, only tagfile doesn't require `<cc:attribute>`-like boilerplate.

Comment: Yes, but then I have to do that for every attribute I want to use. I hoped that there would be a simpler method to inherite all attributes. I guess I have to redefine all attributes then.
Thank you for your help