# JSF 1.x ValueBinding is deprecated, what is the correct replacement?

Tags: jsf, binding, deprecated

I have some JSF 1.0/1.1 code:

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ValueBinding vb = context.getApplication().createValueBinding("#{someBean}");
SomeBean sb = (SomeBean) vb.getValue(context);
```

Since JSF 1.2, [`ValueBinding` is deprecated and replaced by `ValueExpression`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/el/ValueBinding.html). I'm not sure how to change the above code in order to use `ValueExpression`.

Answer (score 18):

The part

```
ValueBinding vb = context.getApplication().createValueBinding("#{someBean}");
SomeBean sb = (SomeBean) vb.getValue(context);
```

should be replaced by

```
ValueExpression ve = context.getApplication().getExpressionFactory().createValueExpression(context.getELContext(), "#{someBean}", SomeBean.class);
SomeBean sb = (SomeBean) ve.getValue(context.getELContext());
```

or, better

```
SomeBean bc = context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{someBean}", SomeBean.class);
```

#### See also:

- [Get JSF managed bean by name in any Servlet related class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633112/get-jsf-managed-bean-by-name-in-any-servlet-related-class)
- [How to create dynamic JSF form fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510614/how-to-create-dynamic-jsf-form-fields)