# Using managed beans with javascript to create elements

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsf, jsf-2

My question is a bit complex, I have a managed bean, possibly A session scoped one, Now In this bean I retrieve information stored in a database about some elements(their width, their height, their X,Y coordinates..etc),  But these elements'number are dynamically stored, meaning they don't have a certain number, And the other thing is they also might have another element nested inside.

Like storing a  div's  position and coordinates, and the p elements inside it with thier information as well, then now i want to use managed beans to create elements accordingly.

1- What should I use ? (now I am using JSF 2 Facelets and Javascript/jQuery).

2- What would be the right way to do it using the tools that you recommend.

I am looking for something that would act like this in the JSF page

Can this be done using jsf and javascript/jquery ??

```
for(every i in elements.div)
{
     create a div element
    then
     for(every i in div.p )
     create a p element in that div
     width of p element = p.width
    .
    .
    .
    load all element info 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use component binding. On your JSF page you refer your backing bean, which provides prepared JSF tree components.

```
<p>Here comes a dynamic content</p>
<h:panelGroup binding="#{myBackingBean.generatedElements}"/>
```

In your backing bean you create and nest elements as you wish

```
...
public class MyBackingBean {
...

private HtmlPanelGroup generatedElements = new HtmlPanelGroup();

public void init() {
     for (Element e : myElements) {
         // Take any element type you want
          HtmlOutputText subElement = new HtmlOutputText();
          subElement.setValue(e.getText());
          generatedElements.getChildren().add(subElement);
     }
}
```

You can also use `subElement.setValueExpression` method to build components with dynamic attributes defined by JSF expressions. For example for internationalization.

Comment: so i create the elements in the managed bean ? is there another way to create it in the facelet ?

Comment: @Developer106, if your structure is not too complicated you can try to go through it using something like `<ui:repeat>` and render elements based on your data. For example `<h:outputLink rendered="{#row.type == 'a'}" ...>`. Another option is to render your HTML source in managed bean into string and inject it without escaping: `<h:outputText value="{#myBean.generatedHtml}" escape="false"/>`

Comment: so there is no for looping and if statements available ?

Comment: @Developer106, for conditional statements you can use JSTL tag library `<c:choose>`, `<c:if>` etc. However it is always recommended to use `rendered` attribute of the elements to show/hide them and keep JSF document tree stable.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at https://vaadin.com/ which is admittedly a different approach, but maybe does what you actually want and more.

**Edit**
Since you can't change the framework (which is very understandable), take a look at [How to create dynamic JSF form fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510614/how-to-create-dynamic-jsf-1-2-form-fields). Basically all necessary steps are listed there. You could take a similar approach to create `<div>` and `<p>` tags instead of form elements.

Comment: Yes, I was afraid you might say that.

Comment: True, but from what I saw the code given will also work in JSF 2.0.