# Create JSF from Xml : is it possible?

Tags: jsf

Is it possible to create a JSF page from a XML file? For example, i make a XML file containing what components i want to be created and displayed on the jsf page, and on loading, xml is parsed and components are created and showm. Either it is not possible , is there an alternative solution (a better way) to do it?

Comment: it is definitely possible, as the views in JSF **are** XML.

Comment: @kostja: true, but possibly in a different format. XSL would then be the solution to convert XML in format A to XML in format B. Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/3511785/157882

Comment: @BalusC - I better not bother looking at questions tagged JSF with my bitty knowledge. You've been there and done that ;) Thanks.