# How to create a <h:button> dynamically

Tags: jsf, button, programmatically-created

How to create a `<h:button>` from Java? I can create a `<h:commandButton>` like  this:

```
HtmlCommandButton button = new HtmlCommandButton();
```

But I can't find the Java class for the `<h:button>`.
For example I need to create this tag from Java:

```
<h:button outcome="test.xhtml" />
```

How can I achieve it?

Comment: AFAIK you don't create markup from Java, but you can conditionally show / hide buttons, using `<h:button rendered="#{bean.shouldShowButton}" outcome="test.xhtml"/>`.

Comment: this wont help me.. It is hard to believe there no way to create it dynamically. I have something like faces messages , like RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().showMessageInDialog(message) .And now i want to change the close dialog button with a redirect button.For now i am using the HtmlCommandButton with a string expresion to achieve that but it will not change the browser link if do not use faces-redirect=true .If i use that then will create a HttpSession which i do not need at that moment.

Comment: It **will** help you. In 99% of the cases, doing things in xhtml instead of Java code works, is easier etc...

Comment: You can safely say 100%, @Kukeltje.

Comment: Still was not able to achieve https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29156426/subscribing-to-postvalidationevent-of-dynamicaly-created-child-component in pure xhtml. But it is almost like developing full components and that is a different usecase @Balusc. Still thinking of hiring you for a day for some consultancy in this area

Comment: @Kukeltje: You know how to reach me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just peek around in [`javax.faces.component.html` package](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/faces/component/html/package-summary.html) for all of them.

The `<h:button>` is represented by the [`HtmlOutcomeTargetButton`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/faces/component/html/HtmlOutcomeTargetButton.html) class.

```
HtmlOutcomeTargetButton button = new HtmlOutcomeTargetButton();
button.setOutcome("test.xhtml");
```

Said that, using XHTML to define the component tree will end up in much better maintainable code. See also [How to create dynamic JSF form fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510614/how-to-create-dynamic-jsf-form-fields) and [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)

Comment: Thank you.It is exactly what i need.I know it is better to create it in xhtml directly but for something like faces messages i prefer to do it in java methods.It is easier to maintain this part from java in my opinion.

Comment: @UtaAlexandru: for FacesMessages you just create the content, not the component! That **is** common practice.

Comment: yes ... but i don't like how it looks. (especially that close button which i could not customize it).I preferred to create a small component instead :D

Comment: @BalusC: is it on purpose that you create the component via 'new' here and in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510614/how-to-create-dynamic-jsf-form-fields instead of  `UIComponent implementation = application.createComponent(...);`

Comment: @Kukeltje: simplicity https://stackoverflow.com/q/16610655. When developing for a component library, of course use `createComponent()` but generally the component library developer should already know that :)