# varStatus unavailable in ui:repeat

Tags: jsf, facelets, uirepeat

I have a question in remark to this site: [http://docs.oracle.com - ui:repeat](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/ui/repeat.html).

I've read:

- [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets… makes sense? - Solution BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3343681/3430698)
- [How to create dynamic JSF form fields - Solution BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3522489/3430698)

How come it is that I can't figure out or read anywhere (that I have found) why I can't get to use the `varStatus` in my `<ui:repeat>` in my Facelets page?

Comment: Please add your code and explain what you would have expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was introduced in JSF 2.0 Facelets (Dec 2009). This suggests that you're still using Facelets 1.x.

Upgrade and the problem should disappear.

#### See also:

- [Migrating from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441713/migrating-from-jsf-1-2-to-jsf-2-0)

Comment: I deleted my last comment.
After an update, it works.

Comment: @BalusC, I'm with jsf 2.2.8  and using "http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets" as namespace but isn't working.

Comment: @vhbsouza: it works for me and anyone else in the world having a properly configured JSF project.

Comment: @BalusC, I've found out the problem. It's an Intellij 15.0 bug on the jsf support plugin. It doesn't recognize the varStatus. Tks.

Comment: @vhbsouza Ever solve this? Latest IntelliJ still can't seem to see this attribute