# How to bind an input value from dynamically generated form to a object of a list in bean

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I am creating forms dynamically from bean. I want to bind the dynamically created components to a list of DTO's i.e a first inputtext value must be saved as a DTO object i.e List[0] ,  second inputtext value must be saved as a DTO object i.e List[1] , third inputtext value must be saved as a DTO object i.e List[2] .

### bean

```
public void addInputText(String value, HtmlPanelGrid grid,
        FundamentsAttributesDBDTO attribute) {
    HtmlInputText inputText = new HtmlInputText();
    inputText.setValue(value);
    inputText.setStyleClass("tile");
    inputText.setValueExpression(
            "value",
            createValueExpression("#{formGeneratorBean.input}",
                    String.class));
    grid.getChildren().add(inputText);
}
public static ValueExpression createValueExpression(String valueExpression,
            Class<?> valueType) {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        return context
                .getApplication()
                .getExpressionFactory()
                .createValueExpression(context.getELContext(), valueExpression,
                        valueType);
    }
```

### xhtml

```
 <h:body>
       <h:form id="form" binding="#{formGeneratorBean.form}" />
    </h:body>
```

the values in the created form must be filled in this list

```
private transient List<ValuesDTO> valuesList = new ArrayList<ValuesDTO>();
```

Please Help me with this issue.

Comment: You already give the answer yourself. `"#{formGeneratorBean.valuesList[0]}"`, `"#{formGeneratorBean.valuesList[1]}"` etc... just find a way to pass on the index. And are you sure you need java to create the inputs? No option to use xhtml?

Comment: @Kukeltje The form doen't have any physical componenets , I add componenets from bean i.e java code to have a dynamic form.

Comment: Read this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510614/how-to-create-dynamic-jsf-form-fields other options possible to. Or take a look at e.g. PrimeFaces extensions dynaform.

Comment: @Kukeltje I followed the second approach in the answer, I can create forms dynamically. I was just stuck in binding the values part.
DynaForm just give the structure for us, the component part still needs to be hard-coded in html which contradicts my requirement.

Comment: Yes I know, but read the last paragraph

Comment: @Kukeltje yes I have read it too , but I couldn't find the perfect example for that approach. I have no previous experience with XML so I've opted for the Java approach. Please suggest me links with the example or code . Thank You.

Comment: How can I now what for you is the prefect example? The code above is very simple 1:1convertible to xhtml. So it if you want to try, please do, we can comment on that. And did you try my suggestion in case you want to stick with java?

Comment: @Kukeltje Yes I have tried your suggestion with sticking to java approach. But the values are not binding