# Java class to create object for <h:inputFile> programmatically

Tags: jsf

I have created a simple `jsf` apllication for file upload but instead of creating a `jsf` input file like this

```
<h:form id="fileToUploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h:inputFile id="fileToUpload"  required="true" f5:multiple="multiple"
           requiredMessage="No file selected ..." onchange="fileSelected();"
           render="FilesTable"/> 
    <h:commandButton type="button" onclick="uploadFile()" value="Upload" />
</h:form>
```

I want to create it programmatically and add it to the form.
For ex : `htmlform.getChildren().add(<File Component>)`

Comment: There are multiple Q/A in at least stackoverflow about creating components programatically. Please find them, try, keep track, mention etc. like requested in [ask]. Now it is sort of a question where you ask us to write code for you.

Comment: @kukeltje i know and already done this with other components i just need the name of the class in my class if you could help.

Comment: There are api docs available for JSF and the source is open https://github.com/javaserverfaces/mojarra/tree/2.3.0/jsf-api/src/main/java/javax/faces/component. And if you know the classes for other components, it should not be too difficult via codecompletion in the IDE or via the api docs to find the class name (that is what I would need to do for you since I do not know it from the top of my head)

Comment: https://github.com/javaserverfaces/mojarra/blob/2.3.0/jsf-api/src/main/java/javax/faces/component

Comment: But more importantly, also read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510614/how-to-create-dynamic-jsf-form-fields

Answer (score -1):

Since I was using jsf 2.1 earlier I didn't find the class,

```
 javax.faces.component.html.HtmlInputFile
```

is the class present in jsf API 2.2 onward and

```
 org.omnifaces.component.input.InputFile
```

is the class I found in omnifaces as an alternate.