# What is the difference between javax.faces.HtmlInputText and h:inputText in JSF?

Tags: jsf

Can someone please explain if they are the same thing when using to build an input field? If not, what is the difference?

Comment: Food for thought: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3510614

Comment: The former is the class that generates the HTML for the latter. Unclear what the confusion is.