# Its possible to remove and recreate a component from a view?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

In JSF its possible to remove any component from view and recreate it when clicking a button or Link ?  This question is not related with how to dynamically create the component its move focus how to remove the component from view .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating dynamic controls in jsf managed bean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370489/creating-dynamic-controls-in-jsf-managed-bean)

Comment: Its not duplicate question of the link provided by you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973384/jsf-2-0-dynamically-remove-components